# How to create an array of Kafka topics using KSQL and bash

Tags: bash, apache-kafka, sh, ksqldb

I want to delete topics at the start of my script but want to make sure the topic actually exists before deleting to prevent error. My thinking was to create an array of all topics and then to loop through and check if the specific topics I want to delete exist or not.

This is what I have tried but I get error unset : [0-1]: bad array subscript

```
#!/bin/bash

KSQL_SERVER_HOST="<KSQL_SERVER_HOST>"
KSQL_SERVER_PORT="<KSQL_SERVER_PORT>"

# Send a GET request to the KSQL REST API to list topics
response=$(curl -s -X GET http://"$KSQL_SERVER_HOST":"$KSQL_SERVER_PORT"/ksql/topics)

# Extract topics from the response
topics=$(echo "$response" | grep -oP '^\s*".*",' | tr -d '",')

# Remove the first and last elements (which are not topics)
topics_array=($topics)
unset topics_array[0]
unset topics_array[${#topics_array[@]}-1]

# Print the array of Kafka topics
echo "Kafka Topics:"
for topic in "${topics_array[@]}"; do
  echo "$topic"
done
```

Comment: The error `unset : [0-1]: bad array subscript` occurs when the array
`topics_array[@]` contains only one (or zero) element.
Unsetting `topics_array[0]` shrinks the array length `${#topics_array[@]}`
to `0`, causing the mentioned array subscript error.
For further analysis, please provide the output of `echo "$response"`.

Comment: Why ksql instead of `kafka-topics --list`?